# Showing a variable more than once depending on another variable (SQL)

Tags: php, sql

I want to show a variable (which is an image) a certain amount of times depending on the number from a different column.

So I want to have $image shown $numberofratings times (which is up to 5). I'm pretty new to SQL, so I'm probably missing something quite basic, but thankyou to anyone who helps!

```
 <?
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alex_demo23");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 $rating=$row['rating'];
 $numberofratings=$row['numberofratings'];
  $image = '<img src="images/star.png">';  


 echo ("addMarker(Rated: $rating $image from $numberofratings reviews');\n");
}
?>
```

Comment: nothing to do with sql, just google "php repeat string" => `str_repeat($image, $numberofratings);`

Comment: `for($i=0;$i<$rating;$i++) echo '...';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a for() or a str_repeat:

```
$image = '';
for($i=0; $i<$numberofratings; $i++){
    $image .= '<img src="images/star.png">';
}
```

Or

```
$image = str_repeat('<img src="images/star.png">', $numberofratings);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$image = "";

for ($i = 0; $i < $row['numberofratings']; $i++) {
    $image .= '<img src="images/star.png">';  
}
```

There's no error checking to make sure that the data is valid, but it should be a start.